Anime about adults turning into children
Saw it early-to-mid-90s.
It was a an animated feature film, anime, I assume it was Japanese.
My memory is blurry but it was something about plane crashing (or arriving in some other accidental way, my memory is little blurry) on a mysterious island where all survivor adults turned into children. A teenage girl had her age intact and had to look after all those ex-adults. Later by the plot she gets to know a dude that owns this island and set it like this. The dude is a teenager too and is involved with teenage girl romantically. He possesses some kind of power source that lets him do what he does.
Any ideas what that could be?

Possibly Magical Princess Gigi and the Fountain of Youth (AKA Minky Momo: La Ronde in My Dream), a 1985 anime Minky Momo (AKA Gigi) film.

Once on Earth, Gigi discovers an island with a secret garden where everyone is a child. In the garden she meets Peter who controls the fountain of youth which keeps everyone young.

The plot fits: Gigi comes to the mystery island in search of her parents after their plane crashed there. It's ruled by a Peter Pan like teen who turns the adults into children using some blue energy weapon powered by water from the fountain of youth, and he falls for her. The film is currently on Youtube here, dubbed in portuguese. Here's Gigi (in her younger form):


I'll watch it and then award bounty if it matches

Thanks a lot! Surely I my memory was a bit off, but it definitely was that.
